# Insert 3D text to the front face of a cube GameObject

Tags: object, text, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to add a text to a cube, which has a 3D text as a child. I am trying to write/show the text to the front face (or very close) of the cube.

I am using the below javascript to write on the 3D text:

```
#pragma strict
var countdown : int = 200;
function Update()
{
    GetComponent(TextMesh).text = countdown.ToString();
}
```

EDIT: My difficulty is to make the text appear in the front side/face of the cube, like it is written on it.

My last failed try was to use the below lines:

```
var tm = gameObject.AddComponent(TextMesh);
tm.text = countdown.ToString();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you adjusted the transform.localPosition?

Answer (score 0):

If the TextMesh object is a child of the cube, then what you'd want to use is:

```
transform.Find("TextMeshObjectName").GetComponent(TextMesh).text = countdown.ToString();
```

where `TextMeshObjectName` is the name of your TextMesh object. I'm also assuming the script is running from within the cube. There are of course other ways to find children as well, so if you like, take a look at this link [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/183649/how-to-find-a-child-gameobject-by-name.html)

Comment: As i say in my edit : My difficulty is to make the text appear in the front side/face of the cube, like it is written on it. Attaching the text or the script to any object is not an issue